# How to get the domain controller time sync event?

Tags: windows, event-log

My computer is part of the domain. Say I manually adjust the clock to be off by 2min.
Domain controller will sync this clock with its own at some point.

Is it possible to track domain controller time synchronization events on local computer?

Comment: The event you see when the time gets changed is Source: `Kernel-General` Event-ID: `1`

Answer (score 1):

Reference [Configuring the Time Service to Log When the Time Is Changed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307937/)

> This article describes how to force the W32time service to log an
>   event in the event log when the time has been adjusted.
>
> **WARNING**: If you use Registry Editor incorrectly, you may cause serious problems that may require you to reinstall your operating
>   system. Microsoft cannot guarantee that you can solve problems that
>   result from using Registry Editor incorrectly. Use Registry Editor at
>   your own risk.
>
> To enable logging for W32time, use Registry Editor to add the
>   following registry values:
>
> ```
> Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters
> Value name: Log
> Data type: REG_DWORD
> Value: 0x00000064 (Hex)
>
> Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters
> Value name: WriteLog
> Data type: REG_SZ
> Value: True
> ```
>
> After you make these changes, you must stop and restart the W32time
>   service.
>
> When the time is adjusted, event ID 61 is logged in the System log.
>   The text for this event is similar to:
>
> ```
> The Time service synced time from time source (SOURCE)
> ```
>
> This is followed by event ID 0:
>
> ```
> Time set (offset < .5) second
> ```
>
> If an error with synchronization occurs, event ID 11 is logged:
>
> ```
> The NTP server didn't respond
> ```

**Note**

The above is for Microsoft Windows 2000 Server but may work in other versions of windows.

Comment: Aren't W32Time service and Domain controller synchronization two different things?

Comment: Doesn't Windows use the W32Time service to do the synchronisation with the DC?

Comment: Mp W32Time service is stopped and something is synchronizing a clock, can't figure out what and DC is a prime suspect.

Comment: [How to sync time on a client with the server time](http://superuser.com/q/605775) might help